# JavaScript - replacement string contains old string and therefore replaces itself

Tags: javascript, url, replace

When used in a browser this javascript:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
window.location = url.replace(/.com/, '.com.nyud.net').replace(/.net/, '.net.nyud.net');
```

causes this to happen with websites ending with .com (and other TLDs when included):

from

> website.com/123

to

> website.com.nyud.net.nyud.net/123

while it works correctly with websites ending with .net:

from

> website.net/abc

to

> website.net.nyud.net/abc

How can I adjust it to make it work correctly?

Comment: This will also reak havoc on URLs like www.company1.net... maybe you can explain a bit what you are trying to do...?

Comment: Modifying the regex to be `/.com$/` and `/.net$/` would handle that situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happening because the `.net` in `.com.nyud.net` is being replaced with `.com.nyud.net`.

To fix this, use one regex to replace all the TLDs.

```
window.location = url.replace(/\.(com|net|org)(?=$|\/|\?)/, '.$1.nyud.net');
```

I modified the regex a bit, so that it uses backreferences to add the TLD to the replace string.  It also makes sure the `.com` is either followed by the end of the string or a `/`, so it doesn't match things like `www.company.net`.

**UPDATE**: Fixed to replace URLs like `website.com/123` correctly.

Comment: Damn, you did all the work for me. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: @user2044638: You're welcome!  I didn't mean to do it all for you, but I wanted to solve it, so I did :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first replace replace `.com` with `.com.nyud.net`.  The second replace then replaced the new `.net` with `.net.nyud.net`.  So you end up with `website.com.nyud.net.nyud.net`

Flip the logic so that `.net` is replaced before `.com`.

Use 
`url.replace(/.net/, '.net.nyud.net').replace(/.com/, '.com.nyud.net');`
instead.

**Update:**
Escape `.` because it is special.
`url.replace(/\.net/, '.net.nyud.net').replace(/\.com/, '.com.nyud.net');`

**Update:**
You probably want to only replace at the end of urls:
`url.replace(/\.net$/, '.net.nyud.net').replace(/\.com$/, '.com.nyud.net');`
but that assumes no path.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `$` in your regular expression to define that you're replacing the *end of a string* instead of just any piece of the string.

Then format the *host* instead of the full url and add anything after the `/` afterwards.

Something like this:

```
var host = window.location.host; // website.com
var restOfUrl = window.location.pathname;

var newHost = host.replace(/\.com$/, '.com.nyud.net').replace(/\.net$/, '.net.nyud.net');
var url = newHost + restOfUrl;
```

Comment: But the replace can be in the middle.  Have a look at the examples.

Comment: Am I missing something? I thought if he would apply his technique on the host instead of the full url, his target would always be at the end of the string?